# Using l20n in the browser with custom attributes

Tags: html, localization, attributes, custom-element, l20n

I am experiencing an issue whereby l20n only applies to an standard HTML element's default attributes.

In my case I am attempting to work with the translations in JSON format.  My dummy data is as follows:

```
{
  "test": {
    "attrs": {
      "title": "my_title_value",
      "custom": "my_custom_value",
      "placeholder": "my_placeholder_value"
    }
  }
}
```

My test HMTL is as follows:

```
<input type="text" data-l10n-id="test" title="" custom="" placeholder="" />
```

However, the browser generates the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-l10n-id="test" title="my_title_value" custom="" placeholder="my_placeholder_value">
```

I have tried various combinations of attribute orderings and attribute names, and it would appear that only the appropriate default HTML attributes for each element type are localised by l20n.

The issue is also evident on the standard HTML attributes such as "title" when used within a custom element, although l20n can handle standard attributes of standard elements when they are placed within the `<content>` tag of a custom element.

The l20n documentation around its handling of attributes does not appear to be very extensive.  So far, searching for answers on Stack Overflow and Google has proved fruitless, and Mozilla host their own discussion list and bug tracker which do not seem to be very accessible to the general public.

The l20n project appears to be in a state of flux, with the supposedly ES5-compatible webcompat/l20n.js in the version that I am using (3.0.5) requiring a Polyfill due to its use of Array.from(); additionally the examples and learning resources do not seem to exactly match up to how the framework should be used.  The source code is completely undocumented but despite that, most of the understanding that I have of the framework so far has been gained by looking there.  I cannot see any filtering of attribute names in their code, so I feel that this issue may be due to the need for elements (and their attributes) to be registered with the browser before l20n makes a pass at the data attributes.

Thanks in advance to anyone who may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

In our l20n.js file, there is this section which controls which attributes can be translated:

`var allowed = {
      elements: ['a', 'em', 'strong', 'small', 's', 'cite', 'q', 'dfn', 'abbr', 'data', 'time', 'code', 'var', 'samp', 'kbd', 'sub', 'sup', 'i', 'b', 'u', 'mark', 'ruby', 'rt', 'rp', 'bdi', 'bdo', 'span', 'br', 'wbr'],
      attributes: {
        global: ['title', 'aria-label', 'aria-valuetext', 'aria-moz-hint'],
        a: ['download'],
        area: ['download', 'alt'],
        // value is special-cased in isAttrAllowed
        input: ['alt', 'placeholder'],
        menuitem: ['label'],
        menu: ['label'],
        optgroup: ['label'],
        option: ['label'],
        track: ['label'],
        img: ['alt'],
        textarea: ['placeholder'],
        th: ['abbr']
      }
    };`

Note that snippet came from the the version of l20n currently published in the standard NPM repo, the version in the `dist/compat` folder.